# how to pass value in multiple activites

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

my android app activity sequence is `activity1->activity2->activity3->activity4`. 
I can pass `activity1` `X` value to `activity2` using `intent.putExtra()` its works fine.

But if i want to access my `activity1` `X` value in `activity4`, i don't want to use `X` in `activity2` and `activity3`. But can't change the sequence. do i have to pass one by one each activity or is there any other way?

Comment: You can save the X value in the `SharedPreferences` for example.

Answer (score 0):

There's always a 'path' of Activities that you can use to pass objects around. But that's cumbersome. As mentioned you can use Sharedpreferences, that's cumbersome too. 
You can use global variables or the Singleton pattern, some consider this not very elegant but it's okay for some simple stuff. 
I'd look into [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), especially the sticky events. It works, simply put, like the mail. Activity 1 puts something into the mailbox, Activity 2 either gets it delivered to it's front door (normal event, delivered instantly) or can go pick it up at the mailbox (sticky event).
This also has it's drawbacks, but I'd not bother about them until you run into them.